# Want to learn a new programming language for mobile development

Tags: programming-languages

I know C# and PHP pretty well, and I have a start on Java, but it seems like a lot of the more intense and powerful applications use either C or C++.  What are your recommendations?  Im interested in being able to target the widest variety of mobile OS's.

Answer (score 0):

Java will give you the widest range of devices (BlackBerry, Android, J2ME Based Handsets).

Widest distribution would probably be C/C++/Obj-C (iPhone and upcoming Palm Pre PDK).

Answer (score 0):

If you're keen on developing for the iPhone / iTouch / iPad, but aren't keen on having to learn Objective C, this may be an option (prices start from $399, but note you'll also need a Mac):

http://monotouch.net/

Comment: I have a few books and starting writing an iPhone app, but had to get rid of my Mac.  Didn't seem to bad at all for common features.  Gaming I'm sure is more complicated.  Does Android and Windows Mobile use the same language for core functionality once you get past Java and .Net?

Answer (score 0):

C++ is very useful to know.

Once you know C++ then Objective-C is an extremely easy language to pick up.